# Error with pivot table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have an SQL query to display information about companies. One of the columns is called PieceType and a company could have many piece types and each type has a quantity. So I want to display each piece type as a column, then the quantity under it. So each type has its own column.

So it will look like this:

[image]

I've created a sample database here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13230/4

```
SET group_concat_max_len=4294967294;
SET @COLUMNS = NULL;

/* Build columns to pivot */

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'CASE WHEN jp.PieceType = "', 
            jp.PieceType ,
            '" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS ',
            jp.PieceType
        )
) INTO @COLUMNS
FROM job_pieces jp;

/* Build full query */
SET @SQL = CONCAT(
        'SELECT    
                c.Name,
                ',@COLUMNS'
        FROM customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON c.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON c.JobID = jp.JobID
        WHERE c.Company_ID = 123
        GROUP BY c.ID'
);

/* Prepare and execute the query*/
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

But I'm getting this error when I run the query:

> Incorrect parameters in the call to native function 'CONCAT'

Answer (score 0):

You've got a few issues with your code that is causing some problems.

First, the code for setting the `@SQL` is missing a comma for the `CONCAT` function`:

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT(
        'SELECT    
                c.Name,
                ',@COLUMNS, '
                       -- ^ this is missing  
        FROM customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON c.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON c.JobID = jp.JobID
        WHERE c.Company_ID = 123
        GROUP BY c.Name'
);
```

Once you add that comma you will get another error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE,CASE WHEN jp.PieceType = "CTN" THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS CTN,CASE WHEN jp.Pie' at line 3

This error is because of your code to get the list of columns. Since you have a `jp.PieceType` value called `CASE` which is a reserved word your syntax fails. You need to escape the aliases for the column names:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'CASE WHEN jp.PieceType = ''', 
            jp.PieceType ,
            ''' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END AS `',
                                     -- ^ add this
            jp.PieceType, '`'
                     -- ^ add this after the comma
        )
) INTO @COLUMNS
FROM job_pieces jp;
```

Here is a [sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13230/28) with the code now working. However, I must also note that you are missing an aggregate function around your `CASE` expression. Typically when you PIVOT data like this you use an aggregate function like `MAX`/`MIN`/`SUM`, etc. If you are looking to total the `Qty` for `PieceType`, then it seems that you'd want to use `SUM`, so your code would be:

```
SET group_concat_max_len=4294967294;
SET @COLUMNS = NULL;


/* Build columns to pivot */
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(
            'SUM(CASE WHEN jp.PieceType = ''', 
            jp.PieceType ,
            ''' THEN jp.QTY ELSE 0 END) AS `',
            jp.PieceType, '`'
        )
) INTO @COLUMNS
FROM job_pieces jp;

/* Build full query */
SET @SQL = CONCAT(
        'SELECT    
                c.Name,
                ',@COLUMNS, '
        FROM customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON c.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON c.JobID = jp.JobID
        WHERE c.Company_ID = 123
        GROUP BY c.Name'
);

/* Prepare and execute the query*/
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13230/30)